Exporting data into csv file not retaining decimal points in a column
I’m working on an SSIS package where I need to export data from a SQL Server table to a CSV file. One of the columns is a decimal (e.g., 5.00, 6.25, 5.30). I’ve confirmed that the values in the SQL Server database are decimals.
In my Data Flow Task, I use an OLE DB Source to connect to the SQL Server and a Flat File Destination to write the data to a CSV. The CSV file name changes every month, so I use a variable for the Flat File Destination connection to save the file in a new folder each time.
The issue is that when the decimal values are written to the CSV, they are not always formatted with two decimal places (e.g., 5.0 becomes 5, 6.25 stays 6.25). How can I make sure the decimal values are always written with two decimal places in the CSV?
I’ve tried adjusting the decimal settings in the Advanced Editor for the Flat File Destination connection, where I can modify the data type. I’ve tried different options, but for some reason, the CSV file keeps rounding the numbers.
For example:
5.30 appears as 5.3
6.00 appears as 6
I’m not sure what else to try. Does anyone have any suggestions?

What are the data types you are using in the relevant parts of the data flow and data sources?

Are you opening the file in Excel?  It autoformats many numbers/data.  Try opening the .csv file in notepad or notepad++  to see if you have the issue there in the raw data to ensure Excel is not formatting it.

Please try to format that numeric value as follows: SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),YOURCOLUMN) in the OLE DB Source.

Trimming trailing zeros is not "rounding". The number to CSV conversion is just dropping unnecessary digits without changing the value. 5.30 is exactly equal to 5.3. 6.00 is exactly equal to 6.  However, if you insist on exporting a fixed number of fractional digits, you can try explicitly converting your numbers to formatted text in the source select list - SELECT FORMAT(YourColumn, 'F2') AS Value FROM YourTable.  Once converted to text, later steps should not trim any trailing zeros.

... SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 2), YourColumn)) AS Value ... or  just SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, YourColumn) AS Value ... might also work, depending on your source column data type.
